# Get href-hyperlink from cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have hyperlinks in a cell like the following:

[image]

I want to extract from the formatted links the real `href`-link. Like from `google` the real link `www.google.com`

I tried using the following function:

```
function getCellLink(address) {

  if(!(address && typeof(address) == 'string'))
    throw new Error('The 1st param must be a cell address as a string.');

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getRange(address);
  var url = cell.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()

  if (!url) 
    throw new Error('The cell in ' + address + ' does not contain a link.');
  
  return url
}
```

However, I still get an error.

Here is a link to my example sheet:

[Link to example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ezyfBuaNB624KIvbb8Dr2UdfdDLo2ROZml5AJobN9zI/edit?usp=sharing)

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom function you quote expects range references as text strings. You can make the formulas work by inserting quotes, like this:

```
=getCellLink("A2")
```

To get a larger number of links in one go, use the `RichTextLinks()` custom function, like this:

```
=RichTextLinks("A2:A4", A2:A4)
```

Here's the code:

```js
/**
* Retrieves addresses contained in rich text links.
*
* When rangeA1 is one column wide, returns each link separately, and the number of
* columns in the result range is determined by the max number of links per cell.
*
* When rangeA1 spans multiple columns, returns all links found in a cell as a
* comma-separated list.
*
* @param {"A2:A42"} rangeA1 A text string that specifies the cell range where to retrieve links.
* @param {A2:A42} dynamic_reference Optional. The same range as a normal range reference, to ensure that the results update dynamically.
* @return {String[][]} The addresses contained in rich text links.
* @customfunction
*/
function RichTextLinks(rangeA1, dynamic_reference) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 22 November 2021
  if (typeof rangeA1 !== 'string') {
    throw new Error('RichTextLinks expected rangeA1 to be a text string like "A2:A42" but got ' + Object.prototype.toString.call(rangeA1) + ' instead.');
  }
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeA1);
  const richTextLinks = range.getRichTextValues().map(row => row.map(value =>
    value.getRuns().map(link => link.getLinkUrl()).filter(link => link)
  ));
  if (range.getWidth() === 1) {
    return richTextLinks.map(row => row[0]);
  }
  return richTextLinks.map(row => row.map(links => links.join(', ')));
}
```