# How to extract plain text URLs from rich text links

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of links copied from the web, links are copied with the names of the original links. They have URLs inside.
How I can remove names, and get the column of URL addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the [RichTextLinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75028882/13045193) custom function. Install the function in **Extensions > Apps Script**, and then put a formula like `=RichTextLinks("A2:A")` in row `2` of a free column.